# не получается получить доступ к бд и админке после компиляции на докере

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker-compose

Пишу веб-сервис на spring boot. Мне нужно скомпилировать БД и админку на докере (docker-compose up -d).
код docker compose.yml такой:

```
  version: '3.1'

services:
db:
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: example
      POSTGRES_DB: todo_app_db
    ports:
      - 5432:5432

  adminer:
    image: adminer
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8083:8080
```

- компиляция прошла успешно, но на указанном порту выходит ошибка: ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED. P.S. один раз компиляция была проведена из другого каталога(отличного от каталога с самим проектом), что, возможно, и стало проблемой. можно ли перекомпилировать этот файл? подскажите пожалуйста, как можно решить проблему?

Comment: Из вашего вопроса не очень понятно как вы подключаетесь к базе в докер. Но похоже на проблему вот в этом вопросе: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53380398/docker-postgresql-connection-refused . Коротко суть ответа: для подключения надо писать: spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://db/droolsTestDB вместо spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost/droolsTestDB

Answer (score 1):

Первое,что я вижу это незалинькованое бд к вашему приложению. Добавьте строку

`links: 
    -db`

К сервису `adminer`